# What is the format of AWS SES messageIDs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

AWS' Simple Email Service (SES) assigns incoming email a 'messageID'. This is distinct from the email's `Message-ID` header, [as described here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notification-contents.html#mail-object) (though it makes it sound like it's for *sent* mail, it's available on received too).

This identifier is 40 characters, lower-case, alphanumeric, and - so far in my sampling - appears to always end in `1` (but that might not be universally true of course - where my account is located, or which server was used may be a factor).

Is the actual structure, how they're generated, documented - or otherwise guaranteed and known?

Comment: Incoming mail?  I would have assumed the sending system's Message-Id would be preserved.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot This is distinct from the `Message-ID` header in the email itself; it's used only in AWS 'metadata', for want of a better word, for example in the SNS notification (under the key `ses.mail.messageId`) and as the object key when the email is stored in an S3 bucket.

Comment: I've added that clarification to the OP, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=76119

`"messageId":"000001378603177f-7a5433e7-8edb-42ae-af10-f0181f34d6ee-000000"`

They look like random UUIDs (v4) + custom stuff around it. Amazon uses a lot of Java so I would not be surprised if they were generated using the Java `UUID` class plus some extra custom code.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID()

Comment: Not that one, I think I receive those too, in a different field, but the `ses.mail.messageId` is lower-case, _alphanumeric_ (*not* hex, full a-z by the looks of it, though I haven't actually checked for each character), 40ch, and definitely not UUIDv4s.

Note also that thread is about SQS, not SES.

Comment: @OJFord Yes this could change any time, it is just some kind of ID they provide.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, because it's an ID generated on the receiving host on AWS side and has nothing to do with message-id header. I'm sure it's unique (time-based+random), but as you've already realized, this info hasn't been released to public. It's also contained in AWS MTA reply to client's rfc5321.data+dot command.

```
 -> .
<-  250 OK e80lsh8r5ju55t3q2m0l8kjre68dipve7vk7kh01
 -> QUIT
<-  221 Bye
```

Header inserted by AWS receiving MTA:

```
Received: from xx (xx.net [1.2.3.4])
 by inbound-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com with SMTP id v49qltmbhp1dkvc17v0uo3ls638pg9l1m9cclt01
 for dev@rcpt.com;
 Fri, 16 Oct 2020 12:04:26 +0000 (UTC)
```

SES json supplied to SNS topic:

```json
{
  "notificationType": "Received",
  "mail": {
    "timestamp": "2020-10-16T12:04:26.671Z",
    "source": "random@xxx.net",
    "messageId": "v49qltmbhp1dkvc17v0uo3ls638pg9l1m9cclt01",
    "destination": [
      "dev@rcpt.com"
    ],
    "headers": [ ...
      {
        "name": "Message-Id",
        "value": "<20201016070426.020156@xxx.net>"
      },
...
```